# Stuck getting proper result after SQL self-join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a query where I'm trying to get an entity associated with its proper location. There is one doctor(id=538).  This doctor can work at multiple locations(praclocid) and entities.  This is the dataset I got after creating a complicated query with a self join:

```
    doctorid   praclocid      entity   praclocid2  LocName  EntityName
    538              214        123    NULL        NULL     ECS PB
    538              214        124    NULL        NULL     ECS JK
    538              214        125    NULL        NULL     Memorial
    538              512        123    NULL        NULL     ECS PB
    538              512        124    NULL        NULL     ECS JK
    538              512        125    NULL        NULL     Memorial
    538              315        123    NULL        NULL     ECS PB
    538              315        124    315         HospA    ECS JK
    538              315        125    NULL        NULL     Memorial
```

The EntityName will only have a LocationName if praclocid=praclocid2. Otherwise LocationName should be null. This is why there only one record with a populated LocationName.

The final result should look like this:

```
    EntityName       LocName
    ECS JK           HospA 
    ECS PB           NULL
    Memorial         NULL
```

By putting the main query into a CTE I am able to get Entity ECS JK with its corresponding Location of HospA.  I cannot figure out how to get the other two entities with their corresponding Null locations.  I tried creating a second CTE to get that part, but it doesn't give me the proper output.  I feel that I've hit a roadblock.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: (1) Show sample data; (2) Show the query that you are using.

Comment: What is the result that you get? The only row you see when you do a SELECT * FROM cte is the one with the LocName = "HospA"?

Comment: The result I get from the CTE is the one with LocName=HospA, but that's only because I'm selecting "where praclocid=praclocid2."  I'm not sure how to get the other entities with the NULL locations.  I was hoping to create a second CTE to return the NULL locations and then do a UNION with the first, but I couldn't get that to work.  I also wonder if a Window Function would help.

Comment: Using the row_number() window function seems to be putting me on the right path.  I'll post the result if I can get this to work.